# Chrome Ignoring CSP Directive in the Header on a Redirect

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, content-security-policy

I am implementing an OpenID Connect client web application. After the user is successfully authenticated in the identity provider, they are redirected back over to my web application. Once they arrive, depending on the value of some query parameters they are redirected to a URL. When the redirection occurs Chrome throws this error in the console:

`Refused to send form data to 'https://my-domain-a.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' https://my-domain-b.com/receive-token".`

After some googling I tried adding a `Content-Security-Policy` header as:

`content-security-policy: form-action 'self' https://my-domain-a.com`

This does not seem to have any affect and I still receive this message.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I fix this?
2. Why is Chrome throwing this error off of a `301` redirect?

Answer (score 5):

After much googling (and profanity) I figured out why this is happening, as well as an (ugly) fix.

During my experiments, I noticed that all Chromium browser descendants (Chromium, Chrome, and Vivaldi) had this issue. Non-Chromium browser descendants (Firefox and Safari) did not. As it turns out, the *identity provider* was setting a content security policy directive of: `form-action 'self' https://my-domain-b.com/receive-token`. Since my browser was getting redirected from the identity provider to `my-domain-b.com` to `my-domain-a.com` the Chromium descendants flagged the redirect from `my-domain-b.com` to `my-domain-a.com` as violating the content security policy set by the identity provider. I unfortunately don't know the spec well enough to say which of the 2 behaviors exhibited by the different browsers is the most correct...

I fixed this issue by doing a somewhat ugly hack. Rather than doing a `301` redirect from `my-domain-b.com` to `my-domain-a.com`, I instead had `my-domain-b.com` render a simple HTML page that immediately submitted to `my-domain-a.com`:

`<html><body onload="window.location='https://my-domain-a.com?my_param=my_value'"/></html>`

This solution satisfied the Chromium descendants since there was no longer a redirect to an unrecognized domain. In my case relying on Javascript is acceptable as the site the user is redirected to is an Angular app, so the user must have Javascript enabled.

Comment: A long discussion about this intentionally different behaviour including the background (e.g. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet) can be found here: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/8